# In Button strike is getting fine, but unstrike not possible

Tags: ios, swift, button

On a UIButton click a pair of button will strike and click another button the strike will not unstriken is the problem , strike function is working fine and unstrike in not getting....

code: unstrike

```
    func updAvaTime() {

    upAvailableTime(sender:time805Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time830Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time905Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time930Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time1005Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time1030Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time115Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time1130Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time125Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time1230Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time105Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time130Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time205Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time230Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time305Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time330Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time405Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time430Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time505Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time530Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time605Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time630Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time705Btn)
    upAvailableTime(sender:time730Btn)

}
func upAvailableTime(sender: UIButton) {
    let currentTime = sender.currentTitle//(for: .normal)!
    let attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: currentTime!)
    attrString.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle , range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

}
```

[image]

Comment: how do u added the strike through in your button

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update the question with codes from above comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set strike and unstrike property for UIButton**

```
let attributesUnstrike = [NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle : 0]
let titleUnselected = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR STRING", attributes: attributesUnstrike)

//Set strike for selected state
let attributesStrike = [NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle : 1]
let titleSelected = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR STRING", attributes: attributesStrike)

btn.setAttributedTitle(titleUnselected, for: .normal)
btn.setAttributedTitle(titleSelected, for: .selected)


@IBAction func reloadtable(sender:UIButton){
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    //Automatically change Button state automatically based on curent state
}
```

**Update:**

```
time805Btn.isSelected = true // To Strike
time805Btn.isSelected = false // To Unstrike
```

> **Note:** Make sure your `UIButton` type should be custom.

Comment: let currentTime = sender.currentAttributedTitle?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString ,   getting   (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) )

Comment: Ma'am, it is just simple code to strike/unstrike UIButton, You have to implement your logic as per your requirement.